# how to auto number ( auto increment ) guid field in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, guid, auto-increment

In sql-server there is function to auto-increment guid fields.

```
CREATEGUID()
```

how can I do the same thing in Mysql?
I'm new in database programing.
I want to create primary key field 16byte auto-incremented.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Just to clarify -- in MSSQL Server, to get a new GUID, you'd call NEWID(). To get a GUID that is GREATER than a guid previously created, you can use NEWSEQUENTIALID(). AFAIK, CREATEGUID() doesn't exist.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling ,thanks, your answer helped me, but I read about CREATEGUID in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd354925.aspx)

Comment: @ShadiSaeed Ah, ok. That documentation is for Microsoft Dynamics NAV, not SQL server (different product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a BEFORE INSERT trigger to check new value for the auto-increment guid field, and if it is NULL, set value = [UUID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid).

This function may be useful too - [UUID_SHORT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short).

UUID_SHORT() - *Returns a “short” universal identifier as a 64-bit unsigned integer (rather than a string-form 128-bit identifier as returned by the UUID() function).*

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has UUID() function which returns char/varchar. You can use, for example, either BINARY(16) or CHAR(36) to save data like that (binary requires some data translation before insertion).

But MySQL supports AUTO_INCREMENT for numeric datatypes only.

Comment: is guid support auto-increment??

Comment: @ShadiSaeed There is no datatype like UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in MySQL. You can use either char/varchar or binary to hold guids. auto_increment is not allowed for these datatypes.